# Cannot resolve method 'toCharArray' in 'String'

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

public class Caesar {
    public static void  main (String[] args) {
       
        //user input
        String [] input= {"bbcc"};

        // turn user input from string to char, creates array.
        char [] charinput = input.toCharArray();

        // Arrays decleration
       char [] abc={'a','b','c','d'};
       char [] ABC={'A','B','C','D'};
/*
       for (int i = 0; i <abc.length; i++){
            // code to check if a char in string is in array abc

        }
*/
    }
}
```

why do I still get the error "Cannot resolve method 'toCharArray' in 'String'"?
I looked for solution on line but all I found was to add  "import java.util.Arrays;" and then it should work but it still doesn't.

Comment: Because input is an array not a single value

Comment: Are you sure the error message is not `Cannot resolve method 'toCharArray' in 'String[]'`?  The `[]` at the end is important.  `String` and `String[]` are different types with different methods.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using String array ,  toCharArray is not present.

Change it to:-

```
        //user input
        String input= "bbcc";

        // turn user input from string to char, creates array.
        char [] charinput = input.toCharArray();
```

This should work.